# Fluid visible in viewport but not able to render

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

I have created a fluid sim which looks fine in the viewport rendered mode but will disappear in the final render. The usual solutions are to check render visibility which in this file seem all on. I'm using blender 3.2.2 are there any other things to check - I'm stumped.
I have also checked that show emitter is on, so it is not that either.
[image]

Comment: Just found where the error lies - if I unchecked the liquid section in the fluid domain, the fluid will then render as expected. This is extremely confusing, and needs to be either automatically switched once a mesh has been generated or something to indicate this is necessary after the generation of the mesh from the sim.